# Import CSS using <link> tag in index.html Vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to include css file in index.html of vue2 app using link tag in head section.

It shows the call in inspect element network tab but response is blank. And the style is not applied in DOM.

When I import it in App.Vue using import syntax, it included successfully.

Can anyone tell why it does not apply form index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VueJS, is not loving `<link>`.. 
you should use

```
<style src="your/path/css/maradona.css"></style>
```

but if you insists just keep mine in /static/.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/youKnow.css">
```